# How do I define the trigger events 'beforesend' in this plugin?

Tags: jquery

Probably a simple question, but I cannot figure this out.

In this plugin:  https://github.com/brianmario/jquery-infinite-scroll

The readme says it fires 'infinitescroll.beforesend', but how do I assign my own function to this without modifying the plugin?

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to attach an event handler (`infinitescroll.beforesend` is a custom event fired by the plugin):

```
$(window).bind('infinitescroll.beforesend', function() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: That's what I have been trying, but the function is never being called.

Comment: Here is what I have.  The infinite scroll works fine, but the event is never triggered:  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).infinitescroll({
   url: "/F_SNIPPET_DEAL"),
   appendTo: '#search_results tbody'
  });
 
  $(window).bind('infinitescroll.beforesend', function() {
   alert('test');
  });
 });

Comment: If I change the plugin trigger from $(settings.appendTo).trigger('infinitescroll.beforesend'); to $(windows).trigger('infinitescroll.beforesend'); that code will work.  But I'd rather not change it.

Comment: @Matt: Well, you have to bind the event handler to element which you have in `appendTo` I guess. Have you tried `$('#search_results tbody').bind('infinitescroll.beforesend',...)` ? (without modifying the plugin?)

Comment: @Matt: Your welcome :) Actually binding it to `window` *should* also work, as the events should bubble up. But this only works with jQuery 1.3+. Which version do you use?